# My regex appears to be complete, yet it's missing matches

Tags: regex

I'm currently working on a piece of regex that mostly works, however there's a few matches that aren't capturing, despite working when they're the only match. I'm hoping someone can point out what is clearly an obvious error, but one that I'm missing.

Specifically, the string `kMad` matches to `[Kk\D]+` by itself, but not when it's part of the bigger string.

For reference:

[Full Regex showing missing matches](https://regex101.com/r/Xbr8F4/1)

[Specific Regex showing matches](https://regex101.com/r/i4TsPS/1)

[Expected matches by line](https://regex101.com/r/pV33tT/1)

Comment: Can you add the expected matches as a list for the input you have added?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera I've added a third link there, though I note that the first line is no longer matching. This is of no matter, as when it's the single string it matches correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-matching occurrence of `kMad10:31-18:5771` does not include 4 digits at the end since two digits after the colon is already captured by `(\d{2}:\d{2}\-\d{2}:\d{2})`. You can define a range for the digit occurrences for the regex section after it like `\d{2,4}` instead of `\d{4}`

The new regex will be:

```
(?:\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}+\.)?(?:Line\d{1,3})?(OFF|ADO|([Kk\D]+)?(\d{2}:\d{2}\-\d{2}:\d{2})(\d{2,4}))
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/31750G/1)

Comment: @BigJazzz, check this out !!

Comment: Wow. I did say it was clearly an obvious error. So it turns out the string is actually being generated incorrectly then, and I didn't realise until now. That's why it wasn't working as intended. This gives me something to work with. Thank you so much. It's solved one problem, revealed a second one, but the second one I can deal with myself. :D